# Forwarding existing Email including Attachments from Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, email, dynamics-crm, forward

I have the following use-case.

A customer wants to have forwarded particular existing emails of a number of contacts. So each contact has emails which can also have attachments.

So I need to extract the relevant contacts, and they're emails including the attachments and send them to another email address.

I can retrieve the relevant contact(s), but now I don't know how to retrieve the emails, the attachments and link them together so that they can be sent.

Can somebody give me some advice? It would be excellent and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an exemple of a workflow that can do this. The entity for attachments is called activitymimeattachment. This code is extracting the attachment from an email and converts it into a note. In your case you should create a new email using "attachmentid", "filename", "mimetype" and I think that should be enough. Good luck!

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;

namespace Dyn365Apps.CRM.Workflow
{
    public class ExtractAttachmentsFromEmailAndCreateNotes : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("Email")]
        [ReferenceTarget("email")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> receivedEmail { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        [Input("Enquiry")]
        [ReferenceTarget("incident")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> enquiry { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var trace = context.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

            try
            {
                var serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
                var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(Guid.Empty); //Use current user's ID

                if (service != null)
                {
                    trace.Trace("Organization Service Created");
                }

                // Get Attachment Count
                trace.Trace("Get Attachment Count");
                var rem = receivedEmail.Get(context);
                Entity email = service.Retrieve(rem.LogicalName, rem.Id, new ColumnSet("attachmentcount"));
                int atc = (int)email["attachmentcount"];
                trace.Trace("Attachment count = " + atc.ToString());

                if (atc > 0)
                {
                    // Get all attachments
                    QueryExpression queryAtt = new QueryExpression("activitymimeattachment");
                    queryAtt.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "activityid", "attachmentid", "filename", "body", "mimetype", "subject" });
                    queryAtt.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
                    queryAtt.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
                    queryAtt.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("activityid", ConditionOperator.Equal, email.Id));
                    EntityCollection eatt = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryAtt);
                    var entities = eatt.Entities;

                    trace.Trace("Entities count = " + entities.Count());

                    foreach (var ent in entities)
                    {                        
                        trace.Trace("Inside the for loop");
                        trace.Trace("Attributes count = " + ent.Attributes.Count());

                        // Instantiate an Annotation object.
                        Entity annotation = new Entity("annotation");

                        if (ent.Attributes.Contains("subject"))
                        {
                            trace.Trace("subject = " + ent.Attributes["subject"].ToString());
                            annotation["subject"] = ent.Attributes["subject"].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            trace.Trace("subject not found");
                            annotation["subject"] = "Undefined";
                        }

                        if(ent.Attributes.Contains("filename"))
                        {
                            trace.Trace("filename = " + ent.Attributes["filename"].ToString());
                            annotation["filename"] = ent.Attributes["filename"].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            trace.Trace("filename not found");
                            annotation["filename"] = "Undefined.txt";
                        }

                        if (ent.Attributes.Contains("mimetype"))
                        {
                            trace.Trace("mimetype = " + ent.Attributes["mimetype"].ToString());
                            annotation["mimetype"] = ent.Attributes["mimetype"].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            trace.Trace("mimetype not found");
                            annotation["mimetype"] = "plain/text";
                        }

                        if (ent.Attributes.Contains("body"))
                        {
                            annotation["documentbody"] = ent.Attributes["body"];
                        }

                        trace.Trace("objectid = " + enquiry.Get(context).Id.ToString());

                        annotation["objectid"] = enquiry.Get(context);
                        annotation["objecttypecode"] = 112; // Case

                        // Create a Note with the attachment
                        service.Create(annotation);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trace.Trace("ex.Message = {0}", ex.Message);
                trace.Trace("ex.StackTrace = {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365apps/archive/2016/11/11/dynamics-365-extracting-attachments-from-an-incoming-email-create-case-and-add-attachments-to-as-notes